# Is product audience spec supported in facebook graph api v2.5

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I was reading facebook graph api documentation. They have redirected documentation URL to v2.6 and v2.7. So, I'm not able to see documentation of v2.5.

Does anybody know that facebook supports `product_audience_specs` as targeting at AdSet in v2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to WaybackMachine for an archived version of the documentation here.
http://web.archive.org/web/20160115000000/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.5